# Problem with const array changing c++

Tags: c++, constants

I have this code that tries to protect the user from array boundary errors.

I don't get why this will compile, tho i've declared the array to be const, therefore, i'm suppose to get a compilation error!

thanks a lot.

```
/************ file: SafeAccessArray.h ********************/
template<typename T>
class SafeAccessArray
{
private:
int _len;
T * _arr;
public:
SafeAccessArray (int len=2) : _len (len), _arr (new T [len]) {}
~SafeAccessArray () { delete _arr; }
T& operator [](int i) const
{if (i < 0 || i >= _len) throw (-1);
else return _arr[i]; }
};
/************ end of file: SafeAccessArray.h *************/

/************ file: SafeAccessArray1.cpp *************/
#include "SafeAccessArray.h"
int main()`enter code here`
{
SafeAccessArray<int> intArr (2);
intArr[0] = 0;
intArr[1] = 1;
const SafeAccessArray<int> intArrConst (2); // THIS IS THE "PROBLEMATIC" LINE
intArrConst [0] = 0;
intArrConst [1] = 1;
return 0;
}
/************ end of file: SafeAccessArray1.cpp ******/
```

Comment: `SafeAccessArray` needs a copy constructor and assignment operator. Look up the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), and the copy-and-swap idiom. Even if this were a good idea, just use `std::vector` privately and be done with it. Also, don't throw integers, throw things deriving from `std::exception`; `std::out_of_range` awaits.

Comment: Please don't throw `-1`, not even in test code.  Throw `::std::out_of_range` or something, anything but a bare base type like `int` or `char *`, and preferably something derived from `::std::exception`.

Comment: In addition, new[] goes with delete[], not delete.

Comment: In case you're using G++/libstdc++, just use std::vector, compile with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` and enjoy libstdc++'s debug mode. Other compiler vendors probably offer a similar feature.

Answer (score 4):

Yea it's `const`, but you did `T& operator [](int i) const` anyway. You're returning a reference, and this function can be called on a const object.

Make it return `const T&`. Better yet, stop. Just use `std::vector` and the `at()` function.

Comment: so, just to make it clear, when i call "intArrConst [0] = 0" - operator[] will cause a cast to a non-const object, or the assignment won't really happen on my const object?

Comment: @limlim: What? When you say `intArrConst[0]`, `T& operator [](int i) const` is called. That results in a `T&`, and then you assign 0 to it, changing the reference (which, being an alias, just changes the value it's aliasing.)

Comment: @limlim: The class contains `T * _arr;` a `const` instance of the class contains a `T *const _arr` whereas you want it to have a `T const *const _arr`. C++ did not add the extra qualification you wanted, so the guarantee is your responsibility.

Comment: @jenny: If an answer solved your problem, please check the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `operator[]` member function desires the following two overloaded variants:

```
T& operator [](int i);
const T& operator [](int i) const;
```

The one provided

```
T& operator [](int i) const;
```

does not match any of the above, and hence the problem.